# Run mac os with VMware virtual machine on win 10

Tags: macos-mojave

I want to setup Mojave mac-os on the VMware Workstation.
When I turn on the virtual machine, I encounter the following error:

> EFI vmware virtual sata hard drive (0.0) ... unsuccessful
>
> EFI vmware virtual sata CDROM drive (2.0) ... unsuccessful

[image: vm configure]

[image: vm configure]
[image: َAfter turn on machine]
[image: And then ...]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/789129/can-i-install-mac-os-in-windows-through-vmware-workstation

Comment: I know I can set up a Mac on a Windows machine.
I've already done this with a Windows OS operating system.
But now I'm setting up the settings for the Mac OS, and when I turn on the virtual machine, I get this error.
The answer you provided did not mention my problem.

Comment: [Guide to install macos mojave](https://www.geekrar.com/install-macos-mojave-on-vmware/) on windows pc. Found this on net, maybe it helps. Although in my opinion its really a bad idea to do so (unless you have a specific reason). Macs are so awesome because of the amazing interfunctioning of its harware and software.

Comment: Thanks ,but 
With this answer, you can run a pre-built virtual machine. This method is effective when we have a vmdk file. but I want to do this with the ISO file of my Mac OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mounted iso is not bootable, you should create bootable iso from dmg or download a bootable mac os iso or download ready vmware disk image.

https://techsviewer.com/install-macos-mojave-vmware-windows/

https://gist.github.com/jamieparfet/0479c938495f88d1b75b30aff318f735